# Issue with xampp

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP without MySQL for the first time.
It worked well and i didn't have any problems.

I wanted to learn something about MySQL and i found that, the easiest way to download MySQL will be rainstall XAMPP.

I did it, but when i try to start runining MySQL i am getting this tape of erroe:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7X8k.png)

Please help

I tried to reopen my computer and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue some years back, the major problem is when you have another software running on the same port as MySQL, if the program starts first before it, you will always encounter this problem; watch out for the programs you have on Windows startup and close few programs running and try again,

I recommend using process hacker software to kill/terminate the program process to ensure it's closed completely.  https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/